# MySQL - Most Efficient query to get multiple settings?

Tags: mysql

Name: Settings. Columns: id / name / value

Example

> id / name / value
>
> 1 / site_name / Blah
>
> 2 / root_path / blah
>
> 3 / something / bloh

What is the most efficient way to select a number of these settings without getting them all?

Comment: Do u forget to write more....dude..

Comment: Are you really asking about the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Alvaro I am aware of the WHERE clause. I didn't know about IN. Writing "WHERE name='root_path' OR name='something'" etc etc etc seemed very inefficient.

Comment: Using `OR` will usually bypass any index hence it is horribly inefficient, thats why `IN()` is a very useful thing to know about. However, be aware when creating an empty IN() because that will be an SQL syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `WHERE`:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE id='1'
```

OR:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE name='site_name'
```

OR with an `in`:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE name in ('site_name','root_path')
```

OR (get only `id`s):

```
SELECT id FROM `table_name`;
```

etcetera etcetera -- this can go on with multiple combinations.

Answer (score 2):

An IN() list. This will effectively utilize an index on `name` column if you have one defined.

```
select * from `settings`
WHERE name IN('site_name', 'root_path')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name,value WHERE name in ('site_name','something')
```

Or if you know ids.

```
SELECT name,value WHERE id in (1,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

If these are simple 3 column rows, and of settings, efficiency really isn't a concern.  I can't see you having more than 10k records in that, and in fact I really can't see you having more than 100.  Lookup time will be very neat either way.  Indexing 'name' will probably be the best bet, as im guessing that's what you will be querying against.

Comment: not an answer. yes i know you are new. but read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).